# Perform UPDATE and setting a user variable in one single query

Tags: php, mysql, user-variables

Everyone familiar with php's mysql_query command, knows that it doesn't allow us to perform more than one query (separated by the ; delimiter) in one call...

My problem is that I wan't to be able to define a user variable in my UPDATE query so that I increment it for each row (kinda like auto increment).
It should look like something as this:

```
SET @t1=0;
UPDATE `mytable` SET `order` = (@t1:=(@t1+1)) ORDER BY `order` ASC;
```

My problem is that, since I can't define my variable and then make the update, I can't find a way to set the variable inside the query.
I've tried to define it if it was NULL:

```
... `order` = (IFNULL( @t1 := ( @t1 + 1 ) , @t1 := 0 )) ...
```

but it didn't worked since the variable resets at each row it works on.

Anyone familiar with mysql that see's a solution?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Old question but here's an answer anyway:

```
UPDATE `mytable` SET `order` = (@t1 := IFNULL(@t1, 0) + 1) ORDER BY `order` ASC;
```

`IFNULL(@t1, 0)` returns 0 if `@t1` doesn't have a value or returns the value of `@t1` if it has a value.

So on the first row `@t1` is not set and it updates as `order = (@t1 := 0 + 1)` and on the following rows `@t1` already has a value and adds +1 each row.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the mysqli library, it allows for multiple querys in one query using the

```
mysqli->multiple_query( string $querys);
```

http://us.php.net/mysqli_multi_query

Answer (score 0):

Going out on a limb, how about...

```
... `order` = (SELECT `order`+1 FROM `mytable` ORDER BY `order` DESC LIMIT 1)
```

or something like that as a subquery?... I'm not sure whether the subquery re-runs after each update, but if it does, it should select the previously highest `order` value and increment it?